# Graph: What does $G/xy$ mean?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

For example:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a $k-$connected graph an let $xy\in E$. Show that $G/xy$ is $k-$connected if and only if $G\backslash \{x,y\}$ is $(k-1)-$connected.

What does $G/xy$ mean ?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, $G/xy$ refers to the graph that is obtained by contracting the edge $xy$ in $G$, i.e. identifying $x$ and $y$.